# Convert pandas dataframe to list of tuples - ('Row', 'Column', Value)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are a few other questions regarding the same subject, but the format desired is different in all.

I am trying to build a heatmap visualization using [holoviews and bokeh](http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/HeatMap.html#bokeh-gallery-heatmap)

My data is being read in as an Excel file into a dataframe to something along the lines of:

```
    Foo    Bar    Bash    Baz   ...
A   1      2      3       4
B   2      1      0       3
C   0      0      2       0
D   2      3      5       1
...
```

The documentation says `The data for a HeatMap may be supplied as 2D tabular data with one or more associated value dimensions.`

Plotting the dataframe itself doesn't work, I feel like I need to get my data into a form like:

```
[('A', 'Foo', 1), ('A', 'Bar', 2), ('A', 'Bash', 3), ('A', 'Baz', 4), ('B', 'Foo', 1)...]
```

Is there a faster way to do this than manually iterating through the entire dataframe and building it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape first by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and then convert to `tuple`s:

```
tups = [tuple(x) for x in df.stack().reset_index().values.tolist()]
```

Another similar solution is create 3 levels `MultiIndex`:

```
tups = df.stack().to_frame().set_index(0, append=True).index.tolist()
```

Or `zip` 3 separately `array`s with [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html), [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) and [`ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
a = np.repeat(df.index, len(df.columns))
b = np.tile(df.columns, len(df))
c = df.values.ravel()

tups = list(zip(a,b,c))
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for the alternatives as well, the third option with the 3 separate arrays is actually seemingly significantly faster than the others, on my dataset it is consistently running 3-4 times faster than any of the other solutions including the one from @jpp - all the others tend to run at about ~5.4ms, and this one consistently runs at ~1.4ms

Answer (score 1):

Using [`pd.DataFrame.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
res = df.to_dict('index')

{'A': {'Bar': 2, 'Bash': 3, 'Baz': 4, 'Foo': 1},
 'B': {'Bar': 1, 'Bash': 0, 'Baz': 3, 'Foo': 2},
 'C': {'Bar': 0, 'Bash': 2, 'Baz': 0, 'Foo': 0},
 'D': {'Bar': 3, 'Bash': 5, 'Baz': 1, 'Foo': 2}}
```

Then via a list comprehension:

```
lst = [(k, a, b) for k, v in res.items() for a, b in v.items()]

[('A', 'Foo', 1),
 ('A', 'Bar', 2),
 ('A', 'Bash', 3),
 ...
 ('D', 'Baz', 1)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer as well, this also works perfectly, but the  zip function from jezrael outperforms everything (not that this was running slowly anyhow)

Answer (score 0):

With iterators and list comprehention:

```
my_list = []
for row in df.iterrows():
    my_list.extend([(row[0], i, v) for i, v in row[1].iteritems()])
```