# Better solution to index a DataFrame according to the values of 2 others

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, combinations

I would like to index a `DataFrame` (`aaxx_df`) according to the values of 2 others (`val1_df` for the columns and `val2_df` for the rows).

```py
>>> val1_df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["aa", "bb"], "B": ["bb", "aa"]})
```

```
    A   B
0  aa  bb
1  bb  aa
```

```py
>>> val2_df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["xx", "yy"], "B": ["zz", "yy"]})
```

```
    A   B
0  xx  zz
1  yy  yy
```

```py
>>> aaxx_df = pd.DataFrame(
...     {"aa": [10, 20, 30], "bb": [-10, -20, -30]}, 
...     index=["xx", "yy", "zz"]
... )
```

```
    aa  bb
xx  10 -10
yy  20 -20
zz  30 -30
```

```py
>>> comb(val1_df, val2_df, aaxx_df)
```

```
      A     B
0  10.0 -30.0
1 -20.0  20.0
```

I put below a solution that works for my problem, but I guess, there must be some much cleaner solutions, possibly via SQL (it seems to me to be very similar to a relational database problem).

```py
def comb(df1, df2, link_df):

    comb_df = df1.copy()
    
    for val in link_df:
        tmp_df = df2.copy()
        tmp_df = tmp_df.applymap(lambda x: link_df.loc[x, val])
        comb_df = comb_df.replace({val: np.nan}).combine_first(tmp_df)

    return comb_df
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to index *aaxx_df* using the values from *val2_df* (rows) and *val1_df* (cols), use [lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```py
vals = aaxx_df.lookup(val2_df.values.flatten(), val1_df.values.flatten())
    
res = pd.DataFrame(data=vals.reshape(val1_df.shape), columns=val1_df.columns)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
    A   B
0  10 -30
1 -20  20
```

---

Since Dec 26, 2020, with pandas 1.2, the `lookup` method is deprecated. Here is a minimal version as a function:

```py
def lookup(df, row_labels, col_labels) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Label-based "fancy indexing" function for DataFrame.
    Given equal-length arrays of row and column labels, return an
    array of the values corresponding to each (row, col) pair.

    Parameters
    ----------
    row_labels : sequence
        The row labels to use for lookup.
    col_labels : sequence
        The column labels to use for lookup.

    Returns
    -------
    numpy.ndarray
        The found values.
    """
    row_idx = df.index.get_indexer(row_labels)
    col_idx = df.columns.get_indexer(col_labels)
    flat_index = row_idx * len(df.columns) + col_idx
    return df.values.flat[flat_index]
```

The code becomes thus:

```py
vals = lookup(aaxx_df, val2_df.values.flatten(), val1_df.values.flatten())
    
res = pd.DataFrame(data=vals.reshape(val1_df.shape), columns=val1_df.columns)
print(res)
```

Comment: Indeed, indexing aaxx_df is a much better way of expressing my problem, I'll update the question.

Comment: Since yesterday (Dec 26) with pandas 1.2, the lookup method is unfortunately deprecated. So I've updated the answer with a minimal version of the method as a function.

Answer (score 2):

Let us do it one line

```py
out = (
    pd.concat([val1_df, val2_df])
    .groupby(level=0)
    .agg(tuple)
    .applymap(lambda x: aaxx_df.loc[x[1], x[0]])
)
```

```
    A   B
0  10 -30
1 -20  20
```

Update

```py
s = aaxx_df.stack().reindex(
    pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([val2_df.stack(), val1_df.stack()])
)
val1_df[:] = s.values.reshape(val1_df.shape)
```

```
    A   B
0  10 -30
1 -20  20
```

Comment: This solution is also much cleaner, but it is unfortunately as slow as mine.

Comment: Thanks for your effort @BENY :) It went from 4.5 ms to 1.9 ms, but Dani's answer is an order of magnitude faster: 230 µs

Answer (score 0):

This code is less concise, but creating a dictionary and replacing directly on dictionary values might be faster than using `lookup`. Also, you can use a unique string of the row + column combinations instead of a tuple to make the code simpler:

```
a = val2_df.values + '|' + val1_df.values.tolist()
rows = np.repeat(aaxx_df.index, len(aaxx_df.columns)).tolist()
cols = np.tile(aaxx_df.columns, len(aaxx_df)).tolist()
vals = aaxx_df.values.ravel().tolist()  # .tolist() makes code fasterfor dictionary conversion from numpy array
b = dict(zip(f'{rows}|{cols}', vals)) #this line of code is the bottleneck on this small dataframe, but it may have a high fixed cost and lower variable cost than lookup.
pd.DataFrame(a, columns=val1_df.columns).replace(b)

    A   B
0  10 -30
1 -20  20
```

For code to create "b", please see Jezrael's answer here for something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50505726/6366770